# App is crashing when UINavigationController is initialised with root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

The method called from app delegate didfinishlaunching and at the line, initWithRootViewController app is crashing on iOS 13.4, iPad 5th Generation. This problem is not coming every time. I got this stack trace of exception from firebase crashlytics.

The method called from app delegate didfinishlaunching and at the line, initWithRootViewController app is crashing on iOS 13.4, iPad 5th Generation. This problem is not coming every time. I got this stack trace of exception from firebase crashlytics.

```
- (void)userLoginUsingNewData
{
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationContrller alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
    [self.mainNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.window setRootViewController:_MAGICBOX.mainNavigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

---

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[__NSCFType fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280183420
```

---

### Stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x197058a48 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x196d7ffa4 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x196f5c5a8 -[NSOrderedSet initWithSet:copyItems:]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x19705caf4 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x19705ea7c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  UIFoundation                   0x19a67530c __UIFontDescriptorWithTextStyle
6  UIFoundation                   0x19a62f6f0 +[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:addingSymbolicTraits:options:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x19b42fe40 _ensureLargeFontGlobals.llvm.1284539462740725553
8  UIKitCore                      0x19b42f9ec __UIInnerNavTitleAppearanceAddDefaultLargeTitleAttributes
9  UIKitCore                      0x19a8350f0 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS prepare]
10 UIKitCore                      0x19a7e5bac -[UINavigationBar _commonNavBarInit]
11 UIKitCore                      0x19a7e5d04 -[UINavigationBar initWithFrame:]
12 UIKitCore                      0x19aa24828 -[UINavigationController _navigationBarHiddenByDefault:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x19aa2b8e4 -[UINavigationController loadView]
14 UIKitCore                      0x19aac3c5c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
15 UIKitCore                      0x19aac4360 -[UIViewController view]
16 UIKitCore                      0x19aa39c54 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]
17 UIKitCore                      0x19aa398ac -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]
18 UIKitCore                      0x19aa1cdd8 -[UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:]
19 SMP eReader                    0x100a4dff4 +[AppLaunch userLoginUsingNewData] + 160 (AppLaunch.m:160)
20 SMP eReader                    0x100a4d894 +[AppLaunch setupAppRootViewWithAppUpgrade] + 108 (AppLaunch.m:108)
21 SMP eReader                    0x100ae5140 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 42 (AppDelegate.m:42)
22 UIKitCore                      0x19b0d4ee4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:]
23 UIKitCore                      0x19b0d6ca0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:]
24 UIKitCore                      0x19b0dc42c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
25 UIKitCore                      0x19a8a9208 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:]
26 UIKitCore                      0x19ad3f698 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask
27 UIKitCore                      0x19a8a9cf0 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke
28 UIKitCore                      0x19a8a9748 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:]
29 UIKitCore                      0x19a8a9b1c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]
30 UIKitCore                      0x19a8a93d8 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:]
31 UIKitCore                      0x19a8ad8c4 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2
32 UIKitCore                      0x19ac70f08 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:]
33 UIKitCore                      0x19ad58c84 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext
34 UIKitCore                      0x19a8ad5fc __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke
35 UIKitCore                      0x19ad58b80 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext
36 UIKitCore                      0x19a8ad468 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]
37 UIKitCore                      0x19a71f2c0 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
38 UIKitCore                      0x19a71de28 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:]
39 UIKitCore                      0x19a71eff8 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
40 UIKitCore                      0x19b0da7e4 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]
41 UIKitCore                      0x19ac91900 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:]
42 FrontBoardServices             0x19c18b7a0 -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:]
43 FrontBoardServices             0x19c1b0838 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154
44 FrontBoardServices             0x19c195f04 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]
45 FrontBoardServices             0x19c1b04f4 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
46 libdispatch.dylib              0x196d25184 _dispatch_client_callout
47 libdispatch.dylib              0x196ccdfd8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp
48 FrontBoardServices             0x19c1d5418 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
49 FrontBoardServices             0x19c1d50e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible]
50 FrontBoardServices             0x19c1d560c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
51 CoreFoundation                 0x196fd6a00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
52 CoreFoundation                 0x196fd6958 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
53 CoreFoundation                 0x196fd60f0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
54 CoreFoundation                 0x196fd123c __CFRunLoopRun
55 CoreFoundation                 0x196fd0adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
56 GraphicsServices               0x1a0f71328 GSEventRunModal
57 UIKitCore                      0x19b0de63c UIApplicationMain
58 SMP eReader                    0x100b5f82c main + 14 (main.m:14)
59 libdyld.dylib                  0x196e5a360 start
```

Comment: `UINavigationContrller`: Is it custom or a typo error? " iOS 13.4, iPad 5": Only on this device + iOS version? Can you reproduce it?

Comment: UINavigationContrller is the native component of iOS. No, I am not able to reproduce it, I got this logs from Firebase Crashlytics.